# CAST or CONVERT in Excel Query

Tags: ssis

How to use CAST or CONVERT in Excel Query ie in Excel Source Task. I wanted to conert a number to Text in the Excel Source Task itself using SQL Command option.

Comment: Check this link once http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.in/2011/01/cast-and-convert-to-avoid-data.html

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use Data conversion between source and destination.
As in Excel source or destination connection manager we can CAST or CONVERT as in SQL.

Please add data trasformation task like below:

[image: Excel to Excel With Data Transformation]

As like the Excel destination it can be any destination after transformation

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems connected with excel files and data types. Sometimes it's very painful.

Check this out:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/355afd19-8128-4673-a9d1-9a5658b72e84

or this:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

When I use xls files I often convert everything to text: IMEX=1 and then I use Data Conversion Task.

So I suggest to change your connection string to:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

And then you can do everything you want with data in SSIS.